# Refactoring a class using ArrayList to use HashMap (Java)

Tags: java, hashmap

I was told to change everything to HashMap() instead of ArrayList() and for the most part everything worked perfect.  However, I am having a problem getting this one method to work properly.

my HashMap() looks like

private HashMap critMap = new HashMap();

I have Room class and Creature class  Room can have Creatures in it.  The Creatures need to be able to react to certain commands which I already have methods for and should work as long as this method is right.  I'm not certain to what is wrong.

This is the method with ArrayList()

```
public void critReactRoomStateChange2(String command, PC pc, String name) {
    Creature temp = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < critArr.size(); i++) {
        if (!(getCreatures().get(i) instanceof PC) && !(getCreatures().get(i).getName().equals(name))) {
            temp = getCreatures().get(i);
            if (temp != null) {
                getCreatures().get(i).reactStateChange(command, pc);
                temp.checkNewRoom();
                if (!temp.equals(getCreatures().get(i))) {
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

THIS IS THE METHOD AFTER I TIRED TO IMPLEMENT HashMap()

```
public void critReactRoomStateChange(String command, PC pc, String name) {
    Creature temp = null;
    if (!(getCreatures().get(name) instanceof PC)) {
        temp = getCreatures().get(name);
        if (temp != null) {
            getCreatures().get(name).reactStateChange(command, pc);
            temp.checkNewRoom();
        }
    }
}
```

the getCreatures().get(name)  is taking the String name that is passed to it as a key of the hashMap to find the actual object it is referring to.  As stated above my hashMap is  thus the creatures name is the String(key) and the value Creature(contains other information other than name) is the value.  When I call getCreature().get(name)  I am looking for the Key String name and I want it to return the object Creature.  If it cannot find it in the hashMap it should return null unless I'm mistaken.

I might just be missing something really simple.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If more code is needed I'd gladly edit this and put it in.
Thanks

Edit: Creature class is a  is abstract and PC, Animal, NPC all extend it.  Just so your not wondering what the random PC and NPC and Animals are doing.  lol

Edit2:  No error besides that I'm not getting the reactions. It does nothing so critReactRoomStateChange is not working now. The Creatures are not getting passed along so the other methods can act on it.

So the 2nd box of code isn't working properly.  It does nothing essentially.

Comment: what method is not working properly? are you getting any error?

Comment: How about instead of adding code, you elaborate more on what your intent of the original method is. Why does each line do what it does?

Comment: No error besides that I'm not getting the reactions.  It does nothing so critReactRoomStateChange is not working now.  The Creatures are not getting passed along so the other methods can act on it.

Comment: I'd also like to point out your choice of wording in your title is fairly poor. "Implementing a HashMap" generally implies you're writing your own version of HashMap, while what you're doing is more along the lines of "Refactoring a class using ArrayList to use HashMap".

Comment: Okay fixed that, I apologize.  Give me a min and I'll take the code out and add better definition to my question.

Comment: what is your getCreatures().get(name) returning in your critReactRoomStateChange method?

Comment: @mauro, actually I think you might be on to something.  I'm going to look into this now.

Comment: @Kirs I'm impressed. Most people don't take that much care in improving their post. You make me wish I had the time to help to really help you debug this problem, but I have a meeting at the top of the hour. :X I can toss out what I do a lot: add a whole bunch of debug messages. It's quick, it's dirty, and it's effective.

Comment: Have you run this through a debugger to see what's happening, and if it's what you expect?  You say that Creature is of type PC, and you want to act on those.  But you wrote "if (!(getCreatures().get(name) instanceof PC)) {" which says only act on those that are NOT of type PC, which maybe is why nothing is happening?

Comment: I edited the post to reflect on what getCreatures() thing does.  And I don't want PC object's reacting the changes as it shouldn't be moving when I dirty or clean the room.  You play as the PC object and the when You clean or dirty the room the Animal and NPC's react.  Sometimes they just do an action and under certain state changes they may get up and leave to a neighboring room to the north south east or west.

Comment: I'm going to try to debug again and see if I can spot the problem this will take me a few minutes so I may not be able to attend any answers or questions about my question until I am finished.  I appreciate all the help.

Comment: I know that the Creatures are placed in the hashMap correctly. I have them printed just for some reason they do not react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that when you were using an ArrayList you applied the method getCreatures().get(i). It could be that you didn't change the getCreatures() method after you switched to HashMap since after the change you dont need to loop and get(i).

Comment: I think this problem comes down to the loop, it is only picking the first thing in the map or the Sting name value.  I think what I need to do it make an Iterator that cycles through the whole hashMap and ask each Creature in that map if it should react to the changes.  I think where I got confused from my orginal method to the new one is I couldn't use a for loop and I just left it out thinking it should work cause you can look up the name just from the String value with a hashMap.  SOOOO long story short that String Name shouldn't be the sole thing I check.  Thank you all for your help

Comment: yup. i thought that was your problem. but your friend suggested you use a hashmap precisely so you wouldn't have to loop through it. i believe you should be able to easily modify your getCreatures method, so that the String name key would be the only necessary input for you to get your Creature object. Less looping = better in this case.